# Dangers of Declaring MainWindow as a Global Static Variable

Tags: c#, wpf

Intuition tells me this is a bad idea... But, I am trying to add some children to an object that is a member of the `MainWindow`. So that the `MainWindow` can use those members later. I can't pass the `MainWindow` object to every method in my app so this was the alternative. I am probably going to make the specific members of the `MainWindow` class the static global variables, but I wanted to ask here anyways...

What are the dangers in doing this? Are there any? Is it bad practice? Why?

```
namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Globals.Variables.MainClass = this;
    }
}
```

Globals class:

```
namespace MyApp.Globals
{
    class Variables
    {
        public static MainWindow MainClass = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the what the members are you need to add to the main window? Knowing the actual problem you are trying to solve might help us give you better ideas/alternatives.

Comment: Well, this actually works for solving my problem... Which is sending a list of status messages. Many of which may be coming from `backgroundWorkers`. The question is more geared towards if there is a danger or if this is bad practice to set the Main window as a static class that is publicly available to the rest of the application.

Comment: Perhpas as a last resort to other design choices. Also, you don't need to create the static in another class, just declare it on class MainWindows : Window { public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; } and set Instance in the constructor.

Comment: @Tom, why can't you use [`Application.Current.MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Most probably the same as always when using static or global values/references:

Uncontrolled, multithreaded/dirty access to the reference. 

If you need this perhaps you can just wrap the MainWindow in some Facade that controlls the access to the reference or makes the operations avaiable to the callers to which they are entitled to.

Comment: @dkozl I didn't know that exists, but I can't use it in a background thread. Doing so results in the exception `System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Comment: @Tom you can't use any UI stuff in a background thread. And no, don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF, that's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore, I'm not manipulating UI stuff.

Comment: @tom `I am trying to add some children to an object that is a member of the MainWindow` sounds like you're doing things wrong. You need to create a proper ViewModel and work with the ViewModel and data, not UI elements. BTW, yes `MainWindow` is "UI stuff", to be clear.

Comment: @HighCore, MainWindow is a class, a variable set in the MainWindow (public bool farts = false) is not UI stuff.

Comment: @Tom whatever `public bool` stuff doesn't belong to the UI, hence it should not be part of the `MainWindow` class. Create a Proper ViewModel. Unless you're talking about something that directly affects UI and is UI specific and completely unrelated to data or application/business logic(such as whether or not the `Window` has an `Effect` or things of that sort), in which case you should not be doing that from a background thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44894/discussion-between-tom-and-highcore)

Answer (score 0):

I think through our discussion in comments / chat that the answer to this question is the following:

Declaring the mainWindow as static is not necessarily bad practice, but the reasons for doing so may be bad practice. When the application has to use a static variable to reference an instance of a window, then the application likely has something that could be designed in a different, simpler way.